# SQL Server - Update on IF condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I can't believe I wasn't able to find the solution in other posts, but here goes..

I am trying to update different tables depending on a set variable, and I'd like the structure to be this way:

```
IF @etape = 1
(UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1)
IF @etape = 2
(UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 1)
ELSE
(SELECT 'Wrong choice')
```

Which returns:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'update'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I have tried using CASE, with the same results:

```
CASE WHEN @etape = 1 THEN 
(UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1)
WHEN @etape = 2 THEN
(UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 1)
ELSE
(SELECT 'Wrong choice')
END
```

Although the documentation doesn't mention this, it seems like only `SELECT` statements are allowed after IF or CASE.
Would appreciate some help here.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (as the tag you used, [tag:case], tells you), it returns a scalar value. T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: What's wrong with the `IF` statements you have..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the parenthesis...

```
Declare @etape int = 1
IF @etape = 1 UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1
IF @etape = 2 UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 1
ELSE SELECT 'Wrong choice'
```

, or wrap your updates in `BEGIN`...`END` blocks.

Comment: Wow. So much time wasted for parentheses. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: np @PYB ;) the number of times ive been caught out on syntax are uncountable!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of updating the table based on parameters, you should use SQL stored procedure which allows you to pass the value as a parameter which is the following.

```
create procedure spUpdateTable
@etape int
as begin
if @etape = 1
    begin
        UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1
    end
else if @etape = 2
    begin
        UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 1
    end
else
    begin
        print 'Wrong Choice'
    end
end
```

Now to run your procedure simply use do like following

```
spUpdateTable 1 or 2
```

Comment: I am hoping there is a cleaner, more straightforward approach.

Comment: Maybe you are right but the method I write is the best method, if you clarify a little more I will write you the codes based on your clarifications, but this method is also perfect

Answer (score 0):

Although I see another answer has fixed your `if` syntax, have you considered just using the `where` clause?

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1 WHERE @etape = 1;
UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 1 WHERE @etape = 2;
IF @etape <> 2
 SELECT 'Wrong choice'
```

Comment: I preferred having the condition show up at the beginning of a block, for better readability and future maintenance.